# Change JBoss EAP 6 port number

Tags: java

In jboss 4 we used dom4j SAX parser to read server.xml. It was working fine but it is not working in case of JBoss EAP 6. .Below is code used in jboss 4

```
public static Document modifyAttributeValue(Document document, String elementName, String attributeName, String attributeValue) {
    if (document == null)
        return document;
    try {
      Element element = (Element) document.selectSingleNode(elementName);
        if (element != null) {
            Attribute attribute = element.attribute(attributeName);
            attribute.setValue(attributeValue);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Failed to modify attribute.", e);
    }
    return document;
}
```

I am getting element as null value .

Comment: So whatever element you are trying to select isn't in that file and might have moved to another file. Fix it by actually performing research.

Comment: i am using this code to get node

Comment: modifyAttributeValue(document, "//socketbinding[@name='http']", "port", "8080");

Comment: `"//socket-binding[@name='http']"`? why don't you just download EAP 6 and take a look what the tags are called?

Comment: note that jboss 6 is different from jboss eap 6, two different products. jbos eap 6 = jboss 7.

Answer (score 2):

Rajesh,

As eis pointed out earlier, JBoss EAP 6.x is based on JBoss AS 7.x code base, which is significantly different than the earlier versions (JBoss AS 4.x, 5.x, 6.x, JBoss EAP 5.x)

Ports are not defined in `server.xml` anymore like in previous versions, but rather in `JBOSS_HOME/standalone/configuration/standalone.xml`.

Try debugging your code with Eclipse (or your favourite IDE), place few breakpoints and step through your code, line by line. See why you are getting NULL, my guess is that your document passed is `NULL`, and therefore your `modifyAttributeValue()` method returns `NULL` as well.

Now, if you would like to change the port programmatically, there are few different ways to do it.

The easiest is to use JBoss CLI (native interface):

```
JBOSS_HOME/bin/jboss-cli.sh --connect

/socket-binding-group=standard-sockets/socket-binding=http:write-attribute(name=port,value=8081)
```

Hope that helps.